# Run length encoding using Scala

Tags: list, scala

Given a list of elements of which some are repeated multiple times, i need to produce a new list with tuples, where each tuple contains number of times an element is repeated **in a row** and an element itself.

For example, given

```
println(func(List()))              // should be empty list
println(func(List(1, 1)))          // (2,1) <- 1 is repeated 2 times
println(func(List(1, 1, 2, 1)))    // (2,1)(1,2)(1,1)
```

This is my best attempt at this point. I feel that i am missing something very basic, please help me understand what

```
  def func[X](xs: List[X]): List[(Int, X)] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case y :: ys   => ys match {
      case Nil     => (1, y) :: Nil
      case z :: zs => if (y != z) (ys.prefixLength(_ == ys.head), y) :: func(ys) 
                      else func(ys)
    }
  }
```

After analyzing what the problem is, it seems to me that at the point when i recursively call `func(ys)`, `ys` does not have enough information to figure out the count of elements. Say we're dealing with `List(1,1,1,2)`. Ok, so,  `y` is `1`, `z` is `1` and `(1::(2::Nil))` is `zs`. Following my logic above, the fact that 1 was seen 2 times is lost for the next call.

**The problem may be that i am not thinking about the problem the right way**. What i have in mind is "go along the list until you find that this element is not the same as a previous elements, at which point, count the number of occurrences of an element and make it into the tuple")

I recognize that in the above scenario (in my code) the problem is that when numbers are in fact the same (1,1) the fact that we already saw a number is not reflected anywhere. But where can this be done please, given that i am not yet ready to compose a tuple

In answering this question, please stick to case structure. I realize that there maybe other better, cleaner ways to address this problem, i would like to better understand what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Why do you expect `func(List(1, 1, 2, 1))` to be equal to `List((2,1),(1,2),(1,1))`? Shouldn't it be `List((2,1),(1,3))`?

Comment: No. Only consecutive should should count for the purposes of this function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right track. The problem is that you can't just incrementally build the result list here—you'll have to pull the head off the list you get from the recursive call and check whether you need to add a new pair or increment the count of the last one:

```
def func[X](xs: List[X]): List[(Int, X)] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case y :: ys => func(ys) match {
    case (c, `y`) :: rest => (c + 1, y) :: rest
    case             rest => (    1, y) :: rest
  }
}
```

Note the backticks around `y` in the nested match pattern—this is necessary to avoid just defining a new variable named `y`.

Comment: In your example, how do we perform a check whether this element is same as next element? Is `y` a special trick we use here?

Comment: Yes—it's essentially the same as `case (c, v) :: rest if v == y => (c + 1, y) :: rest`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler solution using `span`:

```
def runLength[T](xs: List[T]): List[(Int, T)] = xs match {
  case Nil => List()
  case x :: l => {
    val (front, back) = l.span(_ == x)
    (front.length + 1, x) :: runLength(back)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers but explain what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed run-length encoding.

Here's a straightforward, though generic,attempt...

```
package rrs.scribble

object RLE {
  def rle[T](tSeq: List[T]): List[(Int, T)] = {
    def doRLE(seqT: List[T], rle: List[(Int, T)]): List[(Int, T)] =
      seqT match {
        case t :: moreT if t == rle.head._2 => doRLE(moreT, (rle.head._1 + 1, t) :: rle.tail)
        case t :: moreT => doRLE(moreT, (1, t) :: rle)
        case Nil => rle
      }

    if (tSeq.isEmpty)
      List.empty[(Int, T)]
    else
      doRLE(tSeq, List((0, tSeq.head))).reverse
  }
}
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> import rrs.scribble.RLE._
import rrs.scribble.RLE._

scala> rle(List(1, 1, 2, 1))
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (1,2), (1,1))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is called **run-length encoding**. Check out problem 10 of [99 Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) (click on the problem numbers for solutions).