# Grouping adjacent elements in a list

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

Let's say I want to write a function that does this:

input: [1,1,3,3,4,2,2,5,6,6]
output: [[1,1],[3,3],[4],[2,2],[5],[6,6]]

It's grouping adjacent elements that are same.

What should the name of this method be? Is there a standard name for this operation?

Comment: I couldn't say whether it's standard, but haskell has, in `Data.List`, `group = groupBy (==) :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`, which seems to be approximately what you're intending to do.

Comment: The Scala standard library doesn't have this function (the `groupBy` in the stdlib does something different, and less useful), and it's a major oversight, imo. [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) provides a method `groupWhen` which has the semantics of Haskell's `groupBy`.

Comment: You might find *99 Scala Problems* (http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) interesting. This is problem 9, and it calls the operation "Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists", although that's not particularly catchy. They suggest `pack`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `[1,1,3,3,4,2,2,5,6,6]`, a thing like `[1,1]` is very often referred to as **run** (as in run-length encoding, see [RLE in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550537/run-length-encoding-using-scala)). I'd therefore call the method `groupRuns`.

Answer (score 6):

```
@tailrec
def groupRuns[A](c: Seq[A], acc: Seq[Seq[A]] = Seq.empty): Seq[Seq[A]] = {
  c match {
    case Seq() => acc
    case xs => 
      val (same, rest) = xs.span { _ == xs.head }
      groupRuns(rest, acc :+ same)
  }
}

scala> groupRuns(Vector(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6))
res7: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(Vector(1, 1), Vector(3, 3), Vector(4), Vector(2, 2), Vector(5), Vector(6, 6))
```

Comment: OP is asking for a naming advice, not for an implementation.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize that!

Comment: But I have come here from Google and this answer is useful for me, so please keep it :)